# Android OpenGL texture wrong orientation

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to display a png image mapped as a texture onto a square. For some reason the entire image is rotated by 90 degrees. I know that the OpenGL texture coordinate system has its origin in the bottom left corner, but for some reason the image is only displayed correctly when I use the top left corner as the origin (like in DirectX).

These are my vertices and the draw order:

```
static final float squareCoords[] = {
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  // top left
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  // bottom left
         1.0f, -1.0f,  // bottom right
         1.0f,  1.0f   // top right
};

private final short drawOrder[] = {0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3};
```

And these are the texture mapping coordinates:

```
static final float textureData[] = {
         1, 0,  // top left
         0, 0,  // bottom left
         0, 1,  // bottom right
         1, 1   // top right
};
```

The image is displayed correctly when I use the top left corner as the origin like this:

```
static final float textureData[] = {
         0, 0,  // top left
         0, 1,  // bottom left
         1, 1,  // bottom right
         1, 0   // top right
};
```

OpenGL - DirectX coordinate system comparison:

[image: OpenGL - DirectX coordinate system comparison]

Why is the image not rendered correctly?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Are you sure the texture data is not rotated? How does it look in gDEBugger?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Devsil Well, I didn't find an answer to why the coordinates are messed up. The solution I am going with now is just to treat the coordinates as if they were in the DirectX format..